# t-sql Where = null meaning

Tags: t-sql, where-clause

I know this is right:

```
select * from GoodmanLeads where Lastname is null
```

I know this is wrong:

```
select * from GoodmanLeads where Lastname = null
```

But it doesn't complain.  Doesn't give a syntax error.  Just doesn't produce any rows.

Does it have some meaning in t-sql that maybe many people don't know about?

Comment: If you wade through the syntax for an [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you'll find it is allowed because _column binary_operator constant_ is allowed and `NULL` is about as good a constant as any. The semantics aren't very useful, as you've found, but many times I've added `and 1 = 0` as a way to disable some bit of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`null` is kind of undefined/unknown value, so you can't really compare undefined to undefined. `IS` in this case will handle this specially, where as the `=` will be treated like a regular equality comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Null is something unknown, not 0. so, something unknown is never equal to something else unknown value. simply Null is not equal to Null. so that the Lastname = null returns false always